# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

What I am trying to do is have the biweekPay output displayed in the currency format, but an error appears that says cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type NSNnumber. I assumed the line numberFormatter.stringFromNumber would allow the conversion, but it does not. What is the best way to handle this?

```
let biweekPay = weekPay * 2
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyAccountingStyle
    numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(biweekPayLabel.text)!
    biweekPayLabel.text = "( biweekPay )"
```

Comment: `stringFromNumber` returns an `NSNumber` that you currently don't use but need to ;)

Comment: @HAS `stringFromNumber` actually returns `String` ;-)

Comment: I was just about to write that! Thanks, of course it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that the argument of `stringFromNumber` – as the name implies – must be an `NSNumber` instance rather than text (`String`)

I suspect you mean

```
let biweekPay = weekPay * 2
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyAccountingStyle
let biweekPayString = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(biweekPay)
biweekPayLabel.text = biweekPayString ?? "n/a"
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. My only question is can you please explain the line biweekPayLabel.text = biweekPayString ?? "n/a"?

Comment: `stringFromNumber` returns an optional value. It's just a precaution to return `n/a` in case `stringFromNumber` returns `nil`. But if the number is guaranteed to be convertible to string you can forced unwrap the optional.